# Angular2: Why isn't my component's console.log not logging anything

Tags: angular, console.log

This is my component's code, non of the versions do anything. I just get blank console in browser.

```
export class AssetsComponent {
    s = 'Hello2';
    constructor() {
        this.s = 'ds';
        console.log(this.s); <--- nothing
        console.log('test'); <--- nothing
        console.log(s); <--- breaks the compiler
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not loaded then. where do you use it? reference it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If anyone else encounters this problem here's what my error was: in chrome developer tools, under the console there is a setting to hide all output. For whatever reason, it was turned on. I set it back to "Default" and it works now.[image]

Comment: Also, if this does not work, you may need to enable "Verbose" level too.

Comment: In Firefox make sure you have the 'log'. 'error' and other options enabled too.

Answer (score 3):

The possible cause can be eslint, which just doesn't compile the console.log to javascript bundle.
Use this exception for to disable it for the entire file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the component isn't being loaded. You didn't include your code showing the whole component file or your app.module file where it should be included. It's also possible it isn't even compiling, because you are trying to access a variable that doesn't exist:

```
console.log(s); <--- breaks the compiler
```

There is no variable 's' in the constructor you can access. It needs to be this.s or you need to define a variable s in within the constructor function:

```
let s = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after trying to figure this one out for far too long on Safari, so here is my solution. Make sure your console output is set to All.

[image: Safar Console Output Setting]

Answer (score 0):

[dev tools filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUxX7.png)

Please make sure that you have cleared the filter field. Because the filter is applied to the consoles..